# Using a substrate crate for a standard rust project

Tags: offchain

I just discovered substrate. I would like to use, as a dependency a substrate crate which uses sp_io and sp_runtime offchain feature.

The naive code I wrote fails because of "Externalities" and I could not find how to run it outside a substrate node as a native rust program. Is that even possible?

Here is an example of error:

```
'`timestamp_version_1` called outside of an Externalities-provided environment.'
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do? Some crates in Substrate are probably usable (like Primitives), but some are probably not (like FRAME or Core).

Comment: I would like to make it work as describe in the lib.rs test.
I put the code here: [https://github.com/vinamogit/rust-horizon-client](https://github.com/vinamogit/rust-horizon-client)

Comment: Why not use an std http library directly?
https://lib.rs/search?q=http+client

Comment: Sure, I'm doing that now. I forked the crate and removed the substrate dependencies. I would have preferred to extend that dependency instead of duplicating it.

Comment: It's still unclear what you want to do. I mean, why not write an independent Rust program (something like staking-miner)?